# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 28 from storage engine

Tags: error, mysql

I have deleted cache, session and reports as per some of the other threads

I've deleted some other image files and larger files to bring my disk space down and have also paid for more disk space.

I'm still getting the error.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Out of disk space Error 28 from Operating System.

This is happening on the Database Server because it is out of disk space or because your hosting provider has set a database size limit that your database cannot grow beyond for fair sharing of resources (shared hosting)

Check with your hosting provider to have them sort the issue out.

Alternatively it can happen when the system `/tmp` folder is full (separate mount point, disk full). Again a hosting provider issue unless you're running a VPS.

[1030 Got error 28 from storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631387/1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engine)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I've referred it to my hosting provider and awaiting their reply.  I appreciate your help

Comment: @Lisa. If this answer solved your problem or helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql error "*28 from storage engine*" - means "*not enough disk space*".

To show disc space use command below.

```
myServer# df -h
```

Results must be like this.

```
Filesystem    Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/vdisk     13G     13G     46M   100%    /
devfs         1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
```

Answer (score 0):

yes magento does this , it builds up data by itself until your server crashes.
my developer has tried to fix magento doing this but has had no luck.
if you want constant uptime without worrying about magento using up all disk space and crashing your site then i'd recommend another provider like shopify , volusion etc.
very disappointing